# Django Python - Itertools is not aligning products with sum of auction sales

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I generate a list of Products based on two criterias **Entity** and **Period**.
The list retrieved contains all Products and the sum of all auctions sales for each. The example below shows a list of 4 products for Company XZY in November. Out of all the products listed  only one product (sku 30) had two auction sales $180 and $220. The problem is the rest of products had no sales so the null value is not aligning properly with the product. I will need to still list those products and show $0 in sales.

**Models.py**

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Period(models.Model):
    period = models.CharField(max_length=7)

class Product(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    period = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    projectedsales = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

class Post(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    auctionsale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
```

**Views.py**

```
def get(self, request):
        form = ProductsViewForm()
        return render(request, "products_list.html", {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        products = None
        posts = None
        entities = None
        periods = None
        mylist = None
        form = ProductsViewForm(request.POST)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                entityquery = form.cleaned_data['entity']
                periodquery = form.cleaned_data['period']
                entities = Entity.objects.get(entity=entityquery)
                periods = Period.objects.get(period=periodquery)
                products = Product.objects.filter(entity=entityquery, period=periodquery).values('id', 'period', 'entity', 'sku', 'projectedsales')
                posts = Post.objects.filter(product__sku__in=products.values('sku'), product__entity=entityquery, product__period=periodquery).annotate(total=Sum('auctionsale'))
                mylist = list(itertools.zip_longest(products, posts, fillvalue='0'))
            args = {'form': form, 'periods': periods, 'entities': entities, 'mylist': mylist}
        return render(request, "products_list.html.html", args)
```

**products_list.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    {{ form.entity|add_class:"custom-select" }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" name="period" id="id_period" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/yyyyy" maxlength="7" minlength="7" required> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="submit" value="Run Balance Sheet" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <br>
        {% if entities %}
            <center><h4>Auction Sales</h4></center>
            <center><h5>Entity : {{entities.entity}}</h5></center>  
        {% endif %}

        {% if periods %}
            <center><h5>Period : {{periods.period}}</h5> </center>
        {% endif %}
        <br>
        {% if mylist %}
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Product</th>
                        <th scope="col">Projected Sales</th>
                        <th scope="col">Total Auction Sales</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for product, post in mylist %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{product.sku}}</td>
                            <td>{{product.projectedsales}}</td>
                            <td>{{post.total}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Query**

```
Entity: Company XZY 
Period: 11/2020
```

**Expected results**

```
Product -- Projected Auction Sales -- Total Auction Sales
sku 10  -- $100                    -- $0
sku 20  -- $200                    -- $0
sku 30  -- $600                    -- $400
sku 40  -- $500                    -- $0
```

**The results i am getting**

```
Product -- Projected Auction Sales -- Total Auction Sales
sku 10  -- $100                    -- $400
sku 20  -- $200                
sku 30  -- $600
sku 40  -- $500
```

Comment: You stripped down your model too much, cause November is 8 chars.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not stuck on itertools, but want to do this the Django way, then use:

`views.py`:

```py
post_field_name = Post._meta.get_field('product').related_query_name()
field_ref = f"{post_field_name}__auctionsale"
sales = Product.objects.annotate(total_sales=Sum(field_ref))
```

`template.html` (sales queryset passed as "sales" variable to template):

```html
<table>
    {% for sale in sales %}
        <tr><td>{{ sale.sku }}</td><td>{{ sale.total_sales|default_if_none:"$ 0" }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Why? If you're not using any of the suggestions put forward, what's there to look at?

Comment: post is not a field in Product model

Comment: Modified to do it in a way that gets the query name from the model definition.

Comment: this works! do you think posts should be filtered by period and entity in post_field_name so it will limit the search instead retrieving every single post in db which could slow down the query if there are thousands of records?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use the [**`Coalesce(...)`**--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) database function of Django along with the [**`Sum()`**--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) function

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

product_qs = Product.objects.annotate(
    action_sum=Coalesce(Sum("post__auctionsale"), 0)
                                                ^^^^^ this is the default value
)
for product in product_qs:
    print(product.sku, " ---- ", product.action_sum)

# Result
30  ----  400
10  ----  0
20  ----  0
40  ----  0
```

Comment: Yes, depends on the use case. This can't distinguish between sales totalling to 0 and "no sales".

Comment: What should I look for in that code? @RoniX

Comment: post is not a field in product model

Comment: But, they are related through *reverse relation*

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with your use of `itertools.zip_longest(products, posts, fillvalue='0')`, as only one of your items has had a sale, `posts` has only one item, and `itertools.zip_longest` associates this item to the first one of `products`, which happens to be `sku 10`.

To fix this, you can use a dictionnary for your posts that associates the posts to their product :

```py
posts = {post.product: post.total for post in Post.objects.filter(product__sku__in=products.values('sku'), product__entity=entityquery, product__period=periodquery).annotate(total=Sum('auctionsale'))}
```

Then, to construct your list, you can define a function :

```py
def mk_list(products, posts):
  values = []
  for product in products:
    values.append((product, posts.get(product, 0)))
  return values
```

When a product has no auction sales associated to it, `posts.get(product, 0)` will return 0, which is what you need.